# index of max_element with raw pointers

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I've been looking at Thrust and I stumbled upon a question that almost (but not quite) answered mine: [Finding the maximum element value AND its position using CUDA Thrust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709181/maximum-element-value-and-position-using-thrust)

The example posted in there in the answer works fine, but how to do the same thing with raw pointers? Let us assume this code which I believe to be correct (ignore the kernel configuration, it's for simplicity):

```
float* d_A;
const unsigned int noElems = 10;
cudaMalloc(&d_A, noElems * sizeof(float));
initDeviceVector<<<1, noElems>>>(d_A);

thrust::device_ptr<float> d_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_A);     
thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator iter = 
    thrust::max_element(d_ptr, d_ptr + noElems);
```

I can't quite figure out how to extract the position using *iter* and raw pointers.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint: A pointer is a random access iterator.

Comment: True, I think I understand what I'm supposed to do (just subtract iter from d_ptr), what I can't figure out is how to do it in Thrust. Obviously, iter - d_ptr won't work simply because of different datatypes. Is there a way, for example, to get an integer value out of both iter and d_ptr? I checked the documentation and was unable to extract the information from there.

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, you need two operations: 1) convert a raw pointer to a `device_ptr` so that you can feed `max_element` with raw pointers; 2) convert an iterator to a pointer so that you can point to the max element value afterwards. Would these two posts help you: [Converting thrust::iterators to and from raw pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201446/converting-thrustiterators-to-and-from-raw-pointers) and [Converting an STL vector iterator to a raw pointer](http://artins.org/ben/software/converting-an-stl-vector-iterator-to-a-raw-pointer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a number of ways to do this.  However working directly from your code, we can compare the value of `iter` to a `device_ptr` if we convert it to a suitable device pointer first.

The following fully worked example demonstrates this:

```
$ cat t436.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <stdio.h>


__global__ void initDeviceVector(float *data){
  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  data[idx] = idx%7;
}

  int main(){

  float* d_A;
  const unsigned int noElems = 10;
  cudaMalloc(&d_A, noElems * sizeof(float));
  initDeviceVector<<<1, noElems>>>(d_A);

  thrust::device_ptr<float> d_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_A);
  thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator iter = thrust::max_element(d_ptr, d_ptr + noElems);

  int pos = thrust::device_pointer_cast(&(iter[0])) - d_ptr;

  printf("pos = %d\n", pos);
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t436 t436.cu
$ ./t436
pos = 6
$
```

Comment: Thank you, this is it. One more smaller question, if I may: in my experiments, I stored the result of the max_element function directly to thrust::device_ptr<float> and it seems to work as well. Does Thrust do the pointer casting implicitly?

Comment: Yes, it does, and doing that considerably simplifies the code.