# CUDA functor of min point

Tags: c++, c, cuda, thrust

Im stunned. I readed a lot of answers and still can't get it work. Im trying to implement comparator over `struct point`, which will help to find minimal point in array, this is code so far:

```
struct minPointOperator
{
    __device__ __host__ point operator()(const point& x, const point& y) const 
    { 
        return x.value > y.value ? y : x;
    } 
};
int findBestPointIndx(point* dev_points, int pointCount)
{
    thrust::device_ptr<point> points(dev_points);
    int id = thrust::reduce(points, points+pointCount, 0, minPointOperator());
    return id;
}
```

but thi doesn't compile, it just spew a lot of `function "minPointOperator::operator()" cannot be called with the given argument list`  errors

Comment: Without seeing a definition of `point` in a complete example someone could try and compile it is impossible to say what is wrong, but I would wager that 0 isn't a valid `point` value, nor is there a way to construct or cast to one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be helpful if you study the thrust documentation for [reduce](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#ga5e9cef4919927834bec50fc4829f6e6b).

Note the following:

> Template Parameters
>
> InputIterator is a model of Input Iterator and InputIterator's value_type is convertible to T.
>
> T is a model of Assignable, and is convertible to BinaryFunction's first_argument_type and second_argument_type.

This means that your choice of the `init` parameter as well as *the return type* of `reduce` are not arbitrary.  They must be the same type (effectively) as the type of the input iterator (i.e. `point` in this case).

`thrust::reduce` (in this case) does *not* return the index of the minimum element.  It returns the actual contents of the minimum element, i.e. if your elements are `point`, it returns a `point`, and the init value must be of type `point`.

To find the index of the minimum point (appears to be your objective) there are various possibilities.  One possibility would be to zip together (using `zip_iterator`) the data along with an index array (e.g. `counting_iterator`), do the min-reduction based on that, and then extract the index from the value returned by `thrust::reduce`.

However, I think a better approach would be what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709181/finding-the-maximum-element-value-and-its-position-using-cuda-thrust), i.e. use [`thrust::min_element`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__extrema.html#ga90f5158cab04adeb3f1b8b5e4acdbbcc) which *will* return an interator to the minimum element, which can then be used to compute the index easily.

Here's a worked example:

```
$ cat t683.cu
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

#include <iostream>

struct point{

  int value;
  int data;
};


struct minPointOperator
{
    __device__ __host__ bool operator()(const point& x, const point& y) const
    {
        return (x.value < y.value);
    }
};

int findBestPointIndx(point* dev_points, int pointCount)
{
    thrust::device_ptr<point> points(dev_points);
    int id = thrust::min_element(points, points+pointCount, minPointOperator()) - points;
    return id;
}

int main(){

  point data[4] = { {4,5}, {0,7}, {2,3}, {6,1} };
  thrust::host_vector<point> h_data(data, data + 4);
  thrust::device_vector<point> d_data = h_data;
  int min_point = findBestPointIndx(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_data.data()), 4);
  std::cout << "min index: " << min_point << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc t683.cu -o t683
$ ./t683
min index: 1
$
```